# post increment with addition in Java

Tags: java, .net, operators, addition, post-increment

I have following code in java

```
int x=5;
System.out.println(x++ + ++x);
```

The output is 12.

I thought it should be 11.

We have three operators here:

- `+` addition
- `++` (post)
- `++` (pre)
- List item

In which order does the above print statement compile?

If I write `int x=5;` and then `++x`, does `x==6` or `x==5` as I haven't written `x=++x`. Does the new value get stored in x?

Looking for a way to remember operator precedence in Java,or .NET, just like we have DMAS. Is their any analogy for this too?

Comment: You _do_ realise that people wouldn't _need_ to ask questions like this if they just stopped doing stupid things, don't you? :-) Seriously, who the heck writes code like `x++ + ++x`?

Comment: @paxdiablo what if in a exam I have to write output of the following statement , through it carry only 1 mark, should I say "who the heck made this question paper" :)

Comment: @user1765876 In all seriousness, I would (a) answer it and (b) ask the professor why they'd ask a question like this, given that it's something you should _never_ see in the field. But then, I say that from the comfort of post-graduation world, where professors can't affect me anymore. ;)

Comment: @yshavit I agree we dont see such things in real worlds but such questions are excellent way to check /assure the concepts of a student.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x++` is equal to `5` but `x` has become `6`. `++x` means `6` is incremented by `1` that is `++x` is `7`. So `5 + 7 = 12` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ this kind of thing is *undefined behaviour* (since, in those languages, the `+` does not *sequence* the two expressions).

But in Java, it *is* defined. The evaluation order is from left to right.

It's quite simple: the first expression is `x++` which has the value of 5 but increases `x` to 6.

The second expression is `++x` which increases `x` from 6 to 7 and has the value of 7.

`5 + 7 = 12`: Done.

Needless to say, this kind of code is not recommended. And a port to C / C++ would be distastrous.

Comment: +1 for mentioning it is undefined in c/c++ before some c programmers start getting any ideas. As if c wasn't convoluted enough in its semantics

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
System.out.println(x++ + ++x);
```

first `x` is 5, so after `x++`, `x` will be 6, but the expression will be evaluated **before**  the increment, so you will have:

```
5 + ++x
```

at this moment `x` is 6, so `++x` will first increment `x` to 7 and then evaluate the expression. At the end you will have:

```
5 + 7
```

which is `12`.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation/increments will occur before the + operator, one after the other

Your println is, step by step:
`(x++ + ++x)` where x=5
`(5++ + ++x)` where x=5
`(5 + ++x)` where x=6
`(5 + x)` where x=7
`(5 + 7)`=12

You have 2 increments of x, from 5 to 7, before summing x thus explaining the total of 12.

Answer (score 1):

[image: post increment]

During Expression evaluation only [pre incremnted](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operator/) value is used.(Post increment operator is used just after completion of expression evaluation)
This may help you

```
   =x++ + ++x
   =x++ + 6
   =6 + 6
   =12
```

Comment: This contradicts other answers (with 5 and 7) and is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that:

x++  increment x AFTER the assignment in the expression.
++ x increment x BEFORE the assignment in the expression.

So, in your example you actually do 5 + 7.
5 Because the increment is done after the evaluation, so x become 6.
7 because the increment is done before the evaluation, so x become 7.